# Sound Disconnecting

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, alsa

I recently installed ubuntu 22.04 and ever since I had a static noise from my speakers. I researched for a while and found out that my speaker seems to disconnect and reconnect every other second and that what causes the static noise. ([video](https://youtu.be/mEL756UuxYE))

The problem is I can't seem to figure out what caused it or how to solve it.

It's also important to mention that on Windows with the same PC and same hardware everything works perfectly fine and I've never had such an issue, and still don't(I'm using dual boot).

It would mean the world to me if anyone can help me figure this out or point me in the right direction as it drives me nuts when I try to study.

Answer (score 0):

In my case what worked was disabling the power_save mode, which seems to interfere with the audio. Here's the link I found:

https://www.makeuseof.com/fix-static-noise-from-speakers-linux/

But I think that only applies to laptops.